# Websites Web Scraping Emails using Python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

In my Python code i have regex to find email:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
text_email = soup.get_text()
emails1 = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})', str(text_email))
```

About 90% cases this code return correct email addresses.

But below i have example that it return error email format

At webpage:
https:// s7health.pl/kontakt/

we have phone, email and some text:

```
71 342 88 41
info@s7health.pl
Infolinia medyczna
```

source code above text is:

```
<a class="text-decoration-underline" href="tel:+48713428841">71 342 88 41</a><br /><a class="text-decoration-underline" href="mailto:info@s7health.pl">info@s7health.pl</a></div><style>.porto-u-3166.porto-u-heading{text-align:left}</style></div><div class="porto-u-heading  wpb_custom_95aa9a11c17ad45cfabaf210d84ee7cc porto-u-4257"><div class="porto-u-main-heading"><h3   style="font-weight:700;color:#0c6d70;font-size:1em;line-height:24px;">Infolinia medyczna</h3></div>
```

my code return email as:
41info@s7health.plInfo

but should return email as:
info@s7health.pl

apart from the issue of searching for an e-mail using the mailto phrase - this phrase may not be present, why were additional characters added to the e-mail? How can this be solved?

regards

Comment: Do you have some earlier code that strips tags from the text? If so, all the tag data between the phone number and the email will be removed leaving the string `71 342 88 41info@s7health.pl`. Your regex will pickup `41info@s7health.pl` as an email. If you're parsing HTML you should really use an HTML parser instead of regexes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/14853083

Comment: Your regex [works fine](https://regex101.com/r/3tHwba/1) for the content you shared.

Comment: @GillesQuénot i tested this: "r'([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]\S+@\S+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})'" and this returned still incorrect email: ['41info@s7health.plInfo'] . is my format correct ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see your link, but my regex returns what I described

Comment: That means your `str(text_email)` is an issue, not the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i edited post and add what is my text_email: soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
text_email = soup.get_text() - is it sth wrong with this ?

Comment: Thanks to edit your post to add reproductible code with `imports` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://s7health.pl/kontakt/'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

email_regex = r'([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})'
email_addresses = re.findall(email_regex, response.text)

for email in email_addresses:
    print(email)
```

Yields:

```
info@s7health.pl
info@s7health.pl
ajax-loader@2x.gif
```

Comment: thank you, it looks nice, my results are the same as yours - but is it possible to not return string like: "ajax-loader@2x.gif" ?

Comment: What is the rule then? What this email specific?